# Could compression of electromagnetic waves cause red shift

Tags: astronomy

One argument against "tired" light as a possible cause of red shift is that supernovae judged to be closer to us, based on luminescence, appear to be moving away from us faster than distant supernovae judging by red shift. According to the inverse square law, the density of emitted electromagnetic radiation is greater nearer the source. Is it possible that electromagnetic waves close to the source may self compress laterally, thus reducing amplitude and extending their wavelength, then, when further from the source resume their respective amplitudes in proportion to their spectral energies? If so, would not an observer of a relatively close supernova, being positioned in more dense electromagnetic radiation, see more "compression" red shift than for a more distant supernova, thus creating an illusion of faster movement away from us by the former?

Comment: Can you expand on *supernovae judged to be closer to us, based on luminescence, appear to be moving away from us faster than distant supernovae judging by red shift*. Maybe provide a reference?

Comment: Thanks for the link to Schwinger limit. From what I have gleaned (for example  Google "Type 1a supernovae-The Dark Energy Survey), more distant T1a supernovae appear fainter in luminosity than the red shift distance indicated. Therefore closer supernovae  have relatively greater red shift ( the red shift more accurately fits the distance judged by luminosity). In order to explain this result it is concluded that the universe is expanding more rapidly now (in the last few billion years after the Big Bang) than at the time of origin of light from distant supernovae (earlier universe).

Answer (score 1):

Below the [Schwinger limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) photons do not scatter photons, so electromagmetic radiation cannot *self compress laterally* and cause a red shift. The electric fields due to electromagnetic waves just add linearly.